# Can someone help to make this script

Tags: linux, bash, script, boot

Can please someone help me to make script for multi screen command at startup

here is what it is

```
cd /home/bhop1/serverfiles
screen ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -tickrate 100 -pingboost 2 +map bhop_eazy -maxplayers 32 -port 27015
cd /home/mg/serverfiles
screen ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -tickrate 100 -pingboost 2 +map mg_100traps_v3 -maxplayers 32 -port 27016
screen ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de_dust2 -maxplayers 32 -port 27017
cd /home/caln3/serverfiles
screen ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de_dust2 -maxplayers 32 -port 27018
cd /home/clan1/serverfiles
screen ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de_dust2 -maxplayers 32 -port 27019
cd /home/clan2/serverfiles
screen ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map ze_minecraft_v1 -maxplayers 32 -port 27020
cd /home/ze/serverfiles
screen ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map zm_cbble_b4_5 -maxplayers 32 -port 27021
cd /home/zm/serverfiles
```

-Thanks

is there something wrong?

```
# !/bin/bash
alias cdproj="cd /home/bhop1/serverfiles"
screen -dmS bhop ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -tickrate 100 -pingboost 2 +map bhop_eazy -maxplayers 32 -port 27015
alias cdproj="cd /home/mg/serverfiles"
screen -dmS MG ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -tickrate 100 -pingboost 2 +map mg_100traps_v3 -maxplayers 32 -port 27016
alias cdproj="cd /home/caln3/serverfiles"
screen -dmS clan1 ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de_dust2 -maxplayers 32 -port 27017
alias cdproj="cd /home/clan1/serverfiles"
screen -dmS clan2 ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de_dust2 -maxplayers 32 -port 27018
alias cdproj="cd /home/clan2/serverfiles"
screen -dmS clan3 ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map de_dust2 -maxplayers 32 -port 27019
alias cdproj="cd /home/ze/serverfiles"
screen -dmS ZE ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map ze_minecraft_v1_1 -maxplayers 32 -port 27020
alias cdproj="cd /home/zm/serverfiles"
screen -dmS -ZM ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -pingboost 2 +map zm_cbble_b4_5 -maxplayers 32 -port 27021
```

Comment: What exactly do you need help doing?

Comment: SU is not a scripting service. Rephrase your question to be like "I'm trying to do X, here's my script Y, but it's giving me error Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man screen`:

```
-dmS name Start as daemon: Screen session in detached mode.
-r        Reattach to a detached screen process.
```

So you can start every command in its own screen daemon with a name, for example:

```
screen -dmS port27015 ./srcds_run -console -game cstrike -tickrate 100 -pingboost 2 +map bhop_eazy -maxplayers 32 -port 27015
```

Now you can resume this screen using:

```
screen -r port27015
```

I think this is what you're looking for. Just make sure you use an unique name for every screen daemon, because otherwise screen won't be able to know which screen you want to reattach.

**Note:** you should use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to detach a screen. Any other key combination or command will probably just kill the screen and the process running inside it.

Comment: Thanks for replaying but when i run the script it give me ": No such file or directoryash
: No such file or directoryme/bhop1/serverfiles
: No such file or directoryme/mg/serverfiles
: No such file or directoryme/caln3/serverfiles
: No such file or directoryme/clan1/serverfiles
: No such file or directoryome/clan2/serverfiles
: No such file or directoryome/ze/serverfiles
: No such file or directoryome/zm/serverfiles
"

Comment: Of course you should only `cd` to directories that exist. Check if you got the path right. Otherwise open a new question as this has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: i tried to put alias cdproj="cd /home/zm/serverfiles" and it worked but i can see any screen there when i try to use screen -r

Comment: It should work. Try using `screen -dmS test top` and then `screen -r test` to see if screen is working. If it's working something is wrong with your command (if your command fails/exits screen will terminate). Try to execute your command without screen to see what's wrong.